# Disposing MemoryCache in Finalizer throws AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, idisposable, finalizer, memorycache

**EDIT**
See edit note at the bottom of the question for additional detail.

**Original question**

I have a CacheWrapper class which creates and holds onto an instance of the .NET `MemoryCache` class internally.

`MemoryCache` hooks itself into AppDomain events, so it will never be garbage-collected unless it is explicitly disposed. You can verify this with the following code:

```
Func<bool, WeakReference> create = disposed => {
    var cache = new MemoryCache("my cache");
    if (disposed) { cache.Dispose(); }
    return new WeakReference(cache);
};

// with false, we loop forever. With true, we exit
var weakCache = create(false);
while (weakCache.IsAlive)
{
    "Still waiting...".Dump();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
"Cleaned up!".Dump();
```

Because of the behavior, I believe that my MemoryCache instance should be treated as an unmanaged resource. In other words, I should ensure that it is disposed in the finalizer of CacheWrapper (CacheWrapper is itself Disposable follows the standard Dispose(bool) pattern).

However, I am finding that this causes issues when my code runs as part of an ASP.NET app. When the application domain is unloaded, the finalizer runs on my CacheWrapper class. This in turn attempts to dispose the `MemoryCache` instance. This is where I run into issues. It seems that `Dispose` attempts to load some configuration information from IIS, which fails (presumably because I'm in the midst of unloading the app domain, but I'm not sure. Here's the stack dump I have:

```
MANAGED_STACK: 
    SP               IP               Function
    000000298835E6D0 0000000000000001 System_Web!System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdGetSiteNameFromId(IntPtr, UInt32, IntPtr ByRef, Int32 ByRef)+0x2
    000000298835E7B0 000007F7C56C7F2F System_Web!System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostConfigUtils.GetSiteNameFromId(UInt32)+0x7f
    000000298835E810 000007F7C56DCB68 System_Web!System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.MapPathCaching(System.String, System.Web.VirtualPath)+0x2a8
    000000298835E8C0 000007F7C5B9FD52 System_Web!System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(System.Web.VirtualPath, Boolean)+0x142
    000000298835E940 000007F7C5B9FABB System_Web!System.Web.CachedPathData.GetPhysicalPath(System.Web.VirtualPath)+0x2b
    000000298835E9A0 000007F7C5B99E9E System_Web!System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(System.String)+0x2ce
    000000298835EB00 000007F7C5B99E19 System_Web!System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(System.String)+0x249
    000000298835EC60 000007F7C5BB008D System_Web!System.Web.Configuration.HttpConfigurationSystem.GetApplicationSection(System.String)+0x1d
    000000298835EC90 000007F7C5BAFDD6 System_Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)+0x56
    000000298835ECC0 000007F7C63A11AE System_Runtime_Caching!Unknown+0x3e
    000000298835ED20 000007F7C63A1115 System_Runtime_Caching!Unknown+0x75
    000000298835ED60 000007F7C639C3C5 System_Runtime_Caching!Unknown+0xe5
    000000298835EDD0 000007F7C7628D86 System_Runtime_Caching!Unknown+0x86
    // my code here
```

Is there any known solution to this? Am I correct in thinking that I do need to dispose the `MemoryCache` in the finalizer?

**EDIT**

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About) validates Dan Bryant's answer and discusses many of the interesting details. In particular, he covers the case of `StreamWriter`, which faces a similar scenario to mine because it wants to flush it's buffers upon disposal. Here's what the article says:

> Generally speaking, finalizers may not access managed objects.
>   However, support for shutdown logic is necessary for
>   reasonably-complex software. The Windows.Forms namespace handles this
>   with Application.Exit, which initiates an orderly shutdown. When
>   designing library components, it is helpful to have a way of
>   supporting shutdown logic integrated with the existing
>   logically-similar IDisposable (this avoids having to define an
>   IShutdownable interface without any built-in language support). This
>   is usually done by supporting orderly shutdown when
>   IDisposable.Dispose is invoked, and an abortive shutdown when it is
>   not. It would be even better if the finalizer could be used to do an
>   orderly shutdown whenever possible.
>
> Microsoft came up against this problem, too. The StreamWriter class
>   owns a Stream object; StreamWriter.Close will flush its buffers and
>   then call Stream.Close. However, if a StreamWriter was not closed, its
>   finalizer cannot flush its buffers. Microsoft "solved" this problem by
>   not giving StreamWriter a finalizer, hoping that programmers will
>   notice the missing data and deduce their error. This is a perfect
>   example of the need for shutdown logic.

All that said, I think that it should be possible to implement "managed finalization" using WeakReference. Basically, have your class register a WeakReference to itself and a finalize action with some queue when the object is created. The queue is then monitored by a background thread or timer which calls the appropriate action when it's paired WeakReference gets collected. Of course, you'd have to be careful that your finalize action doesn't inadvertantly hold onto the class itself, thus preventing collection altogether!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should never dispose of a managed object in the finalizer, instead that should be done in the normal `IDisposable.Dispose`.  The finalizer should only be cleaning up unmanaged objects.

Comment: @juharr: In this case, though, the object is "unmanaged" in the sense that it will NEVER be garbage collected unless explicitly disposed.

Comment: @juharr: A managed resource is an object which holds external resources, but will release them if it is abandoned.  Things which hold external resources but won't release them if abandoned need to be treated as unmanaged resources, even though in many cases they *can't* be cleaned up with finalizers and so the only remedy is to ensure that they never get abandoned in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't Dispose managed objects in the finalizer, as they might have already been finalized (or, as you've seen here, portions of the environment may no longer be in the state you're expecting.)  This means that if you contain a class which must be Disposed explicitly, your class must also be Disposed explicitly.  There's no way to 'cheat' and make the Disposal automatic.  Unfortunately, garbage collection is, in cases like this, a leaky abstraction.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any explicit documentation for this rule? The things I've read always use the term "unmanaged resources", which I took to mean anything that could not be cleaned up by the GC. Does this also mean that you can basically only work with OS handles in finalizers? For example, if I had a string path for a file I wanted to delete, would it be valid for my finalizer to reference that string in order to delete that file?

Comment: You should really not be running any code in your finalizer that does not explicitly close an unmanaged resource using a handle like an `IntPtr`.  Performing any kind of I/O on the finalizer thread is a very bad idea, and can lead to precisely the kinds of issues that you're seeing.  You have no idea what the security context will be when your finalizer runs.

Comment: @MikeStrobel thanks for the additional detail. Can you point to any official documentation for this?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion There is a lot of useful information in the [MSDN documentation for `Object.Finalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx).  Some recommendations, like not performing I/O, may require reading between the lines: you have no idea when finalization will occur, or on what thread, which automatically has implications for any operations that are blocking and/or have security demands.

Comment: So far as I can tell, MS never really defines "unmanaged resource".  It offers examples, but no definition.  I would define it as you seem to: an external resource that won't be automatically cleaned up if an object is abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that objects with finalizers should generally not be exposed to the outside world, and should only hold strong references to things which are actually needed for finalization and are not exposed to anything in the outside world that is not expecting them to be used for that purpose.  Public-facing types should not have finalizers themselves, but should instead encapsulate cleanup logic within privately-held instances of finalizable classes whose *purpose* is to encapsulate such logic.

The only time it really makes sense for a finalizer to attempt to clean up a resource which is owned by another object is when the other object is *designed* to interface with the finalizer.  I can't think of any places where Framework classes have engineered in the proper hooks, but will offer an example how Microsoft *could* have engineered them to do so.

A `File` object could offer an event with thread-safe subscribe and unsubscribe methods which would fire (notifying the last subscriber first) when the `File` object receives either a `Dispose` call or a `finalize` request.  The event would fire between the time `Finalize` is called and the time the encapsulated file is actually closed, and could be used by a an external buffering class as a signal that it needs to give the `File` any information which it has received but not yet passed along.

Note that to make such a thing work properly and safely, it would be necessary that the part of the `File` object which has the finalizer not be exposed to the public, and that it use a long weak reference to ensure that if it runs while the public-facing object is still alive, it will reregister itself for finalization.  Note that if the only reference to a `WeakReference` object is stored in a finalizable object, its `Target` property may be invalidated if the finalizable object becomes eligible for finalization *even if the actual target of the reference is still alive*.  Defective design, IMHO, and one which must be worked around somewhat carefully.

It's possible to design objects with finalizers that can cooperate (the easiest way to do it, generally, is to only have one object in the group sport a finalizer), but if things aren't designed to cooperate with finalizers, the best that one can do is generally have a finalizer sound an alarm indicating "This object wasn't supposed to be `Dispose`d but wasn't; because it wasn't, resources are going to leak, and there's nothing to be done about it except fix the code to dispose the object properly in future".