# ASP .NET Error when redirect to another page: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, telerik

I tried to run the web and it's redirect me to my dashboard after my logging in. the database working find. data are displayed correctly. but when i tried to redirect to another page this error appeared: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

on my friend computer is working find.

[screenshot error break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRErH.png)

here is the code

```
protected void bindGvProject()
    {
        Session.Remove(GV_PROJECT);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (ProjectWS.ProjectWebService ws = new ProjectWS.ProjectWebService())
            {
                ws.InsertAuditLog("Project", "Project.aspx.cs", 186, c.GetIP(), "GetProjects", CommonVariable.ACTION_RETRIEVE, loginName, DateTime.Now);
                dt = ws.GetProjects();
                Session[GV_PROJECT] = dt;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            c.LogError("Project > Project: Error on SearchProject", ex, false);
        }

        gvProject.DataSource = dt;
        gvProject.DataBind(); // error at here

        upnlSearch.Update();
        upnlSidePanel.Update();
        lbtnTotalProject.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

Error Stack:

> System.AccessViolationException occurred   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.   Source=System.Web
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdGetSiteNameFromId(IntPtr
>   pConfigSystem, UInt32 siteId, IntPtr& bstrSiteName, Int32&
>   cchSiteName)
>          at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostConfigUtils.GetSiteNameFromId(UInt32
>   siteId)
>          at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.MapPathCaching(String
>   siteID, VirtualPath path)
>          at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.GetPathConfigFilenameWorker(String
>   siteID, VirtualPath path, String& directory, String& baseName)
>          at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPath.GetPathConfigFilename(String
>   siteID, String path, String& directory, String& baseName)
>          at System.Web.Configuration.HostingPreferredMapPath.GetPathConfigFilename(String
>   siteID, String path, String& directory, String& baseName)
>          at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String
>   configPath)
>          at System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.GetStreamName(String
>   configPath)
>          at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
>          at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Init(IInternalConfigRoot
>   configRoot, BaseConfigurationRecord parent, String configPath, String
>   locationSubPath)
>          at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.GetConfigRecord(String
>   configPath)
>          at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor(String locationSubPath, Type typeConfigHost, Object[]
>   hostInitConfigurationParams)
>          at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigConfigurationFactory.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigConfigurationFactory.Create(Type
>   typeConfigHost, Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams)
>          at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.OpenConfiguration(WebLevel
>   webLevel, ConfigurationFileMap fileMap, VirtualPath path, String site,
>   String locationSubPath, String server, String userName, String
>   password, IntPtr tokenHandle)
>          at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(String
>   path)
>          at Telerik.Web.X_UA_CompatbileReader.LoadWebServerConfig(String applicationPath)
>          at Telerik.Web.X_UA_CompatbileReader.IsEdge(HttpContext context)
>          at Telerik.Web.UI.RenderModeBrowserAdaptor.get_Instance()
>          at Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompositeDataBoundControl.ResolveRenderMode()
>          at Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompositeDataBoundControl.get_ResolvedRenderMode()
>          at Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.get_GroupPanelPosition()
>          at Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data)
>          at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback)
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>          at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind()
>          at Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.DataBind()
>          at Project.bindGvProject() in c:\Users\firga\Desktop\Nimrod\EMS\project\project.aspx.cs:line 291
>   InnerException:

Comment: Is it possible you are impacted by https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/155558-bitmining-software-disguised-as-aspnetexe/ or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet.caching/eBZTxmmcmrs ?

Comment: Are there any finalizers in your code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264528/disposing-memorycache-in-finalizer-throws-accessviolationexception ?

Comment: Project Properties->Build and change "Platform Target" to x86. Try that

Comment: maybe try restart visual studio as administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run my application without enter my windows 10 pro key (so i running with windows 10 home) it's worked. the bug is disappear. may be something going wrong with my windows update or else.